# How to bind a button to show and hide based on click

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a list of headers (titles) and each has paragraphs... I created a list for this so that it has a button with icon on the right. when the button is clicked , show the paragraph and when clicked again it should hide it back.

on the first click its shown but I don't know how to hide it back when its clicked again.

so far I have done something like this:

.html:

```
<ion-list no-lines>
  <button ion-item (click)="itemClicked()">
    <h2>About {{details.company.data.company_name_en}}</h2>
     <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-down" item-right></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <div [style.visibility]= "toggoleShowHide">
    <p dir="auto" >
      {{details.company_profile}}
    </p>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

.ts:

```
itemClicked(){
this.toggoleShowHide= 'visible';
}
```

Also , the space for the `<div>` tags are also not hidden.....And if someone can please suggest how to animate this properly..... when clicked the list should expand with the content inside , and then contract when clicked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For animations you can check out [The Guide for Angular Animations](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#example-transitioning-between-states)

where you use `animations` to your component and can apply different styles to your animation.

With animations you can use `[@triggerName]` (name it as you want) to attach the animation to elements, and this is triggered by your click event. Then in your component you add the logic in `animations`, so it could look something like this:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      state('collapsed, void',
        style({ height:"0px"})),
      state('expanded',
        style({ height:"*" })),
      transition("collapsed <=> expanded", [
        animate(500, style({ height: '250px'})),
        animate(500)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Here in this example we toggle the state between `collapsed` and `expanded` and apply styles and timing for `openClose`. The above code does nothing special animation-wise. But that's where you come in and can apply whatever style you want!

Here is a simple working example:

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h8WtgDmKM3EEU0vv60Ox?p=preview)

Comment: hi there, there is a problem in this line `animate(500, style({ height: '100px'}))` How can I set it to be dynamic, since the animated items are paragraphs and their heights can come big or small....if i set it to `auto` the animation seems to disappear

Comment: The same link I provided, has this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#automatic-property-calculation that should help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[hidden]="true/false"` directive

**ts**:

```
this.toggoleShowHide = true;

itemClicked(){
  this.toggoleShowHide = !this.toggoleShowHide;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div [hidden]= "toggoleShowHide">
    <p dir="auto" >
      {{details.company_profile}}
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanx that worked..... but can you suggest something for animation , like fadeIn and fadeOut... how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled in html itself

```
<ion-list no-lines>
 <button ion-button clear item-end class="roundButton" (click)="viewType = !viewType">
  <h2>About {{details.company.data.company_name_en}}</h2>
   <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-down" item-right></ion-icon>
 </button>
 <ion-item *ngIf="viewType">
  <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```